# If an application opens 2 TCP sockets, will the in-order property be maintained across both of them?

Tags: javascript, sockets, networking, tcp, websocket

If I have a Javascript application that opens 2 websockets in parallel, where both are to the same host on the same port:

```
var socket1 = io.connect(host);
var socket2 = io.connect(host);
```

And then I send data from each of them to the same function in the application:

```
socket1.on("data", function(e) {doStuff(e);});
socket2.on("data", function(e) {doStuff(e);});
```

Will each socket have the in-order property enforced only for itself, or will it be enforced for the  whole application? For example, if a packet sent to socket1 gets lost, will socket2 still be able to receive and process future TCP packets without having to wait for the re-transmission of packets to socket1?

Answer (score 5):

The two sockets will be completely independent.  Data sent on one connection will have no effect on the other, regardless of loss and retransmission.  Specifically, the sequence-number-space used by TCP for data integrity is specific to the four-tuple of (addr1, port1, addr2, port2).

Comment: But suppose they are communicating with the same server on the same port? Wouldn't that tuple be identical for both connections?

Comment: @Joey No, it wouldn't be.  Two different ports would be used on the client.  Also remember that Web Sockets is a separate protocol which runs over TCP, and Socket.IO is another protocol on top of Web Sockets **or** some other transport.  Your question is confusing all of these layers.  In fact, there is no need for a persistent connection at all for Socket.IO to work.

Comment: @Brad is correct.  A TCP connection is **defined** by that four-tuple.  If you're using the same port numbers on both connections, you don't have two TCP connections, you have one.  But you don't - each WebSocket is a separate client-side port number.